# Poner STRICT_ALL_TABLES en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda, es necesario poner el STRICT_ALL_TABLES o STRICT_TRANS_TABLES para los inserts y updates en un ambiente de producción o solo en ambiente de pruebas o debería ser en las dos?.

Lo pregunto porque tengo proyectos en los que esta deshabilitado y cuando lo habilito, varios inserts y updates dejan de funcionar, entonces es para saber si vale la pena hacer la corrección en el código y habilitar el STRICT_ALL_TABLES o mejor dejo el código como esta con el STRICT_ALL_TABLES deshabilitado.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

estás indicando el modo estricto en todas las tablas. Si el INSERT o UPDATE te falla es porque encuentra valores no válidos. En un SELECT por ejemplo que no hace cambios, solo consultas, en lugar de fallar te mostrará un mensaje.
Deberías revisar cuales son los fallos que tienes y solucionarlos. Sobre todo fíjate en datos faltantes, valores Null, etc...